# Qual a melhor forma de editar uma entidade com Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

No meu Controller tenho o seguinte mapeamento para exibir o formulário de edição do cadastro de uma pessoa:

```
@GetMapping("/mostraEmpresaEdicao/{idpessoa}")
    public ModelAndView mostraEmpresaEdicao(@PathVariable("idpessoa") Long idpessoa) {
        
        Optional<Pessoa> pessoa = pessoaRepository.findById(idpessoa);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("cadastro/editarpessoa");
        modelAndView.addObject("pessoaobj", pessoa.get());
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

A pessoa é carregada no formulário editarpessoa.html. Qual a melhor forma de editar essa pessoa? Supondo que é possível editar todos os campos de uma pessoa. Eu posso colocar a ação desse formulário para o meu método de salvar, que eu também utilizo para salvar um novo cadastro?

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/salvarpessoa")
    public ModelAndView salvar(Pessoa pessoa) {
        pessoaRepository.save(pessoa);
        return pessoas();
    }
```

OBS: O pessoas() é um método para listar os cadastros.

editarpessoa.html com a ação para /salvarpessoa, utilizada também em novos cadastros:

```
    <form action="#" 
          th:action="@{/salvarpessoa}"
          th:object="${pessoaobj}" 
          method="post">
         <label>Id</label>
         <input name="id" readonly="readonly" th:field="*{id}">
         <label>Nome</label>
         <input name="nome" th:field="*{nome}">
         <label>Sobrenome</label>
         <input name="sobrenome" th:field="*{sobrenome}">   
    
         <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="salvar">Salvar
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
         </button>
         
    </form>
```

Ou o mais correto é criar um mapeamento próprio para o editar, alterando a action do formulário para ele?

```
    @PostMapping("/editarpessoa/{idpessoa}")
    public String editar(Pessoa pessoaedicao) {
        
        Optional<Pessoa> pessoa = pessoaRepository.findById(pessoaedicao.getId());
        pessoa.get().setNome(pessoaedicao.getNome());
        pessoa.get().setSobrenome(pessoaedicao.getSobrenome());
        pessoaRepository.save(pessoa.get());
            
        return "cadastro/cadastropessoa";
    }
```

Caso o ideal seja criar um método separado, é correto utilizar o set() para alterar os campos da entidade e depois o save(), ou não há problema em usar apenas o save()? No fundo, o Spring Data vai ver que o ID já existe e vai dar o update?

```
    @PostMapping("/editarpessoa/{idpessoa}")
    public String editar(@PathVariable("idpessoa") Long idpessoa, Pessoa pessoaedicao) {
        
        Optional<Pessoa> pessoa = pessoaRepository.findById(idpessoa);
        pessoaRepository.save(pessoa.get());
            
        return "cadastro/cadastropessoa";
    }
```

Verificando o manual, o método save faz o persist se a entidade for nova, e o merge se ela já existir:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        this.em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return this.em.merge(entity);
     }
 }
```

Então acredito que se os dados que eu vou editar são os mesmos de um novo cadastro, não uso algum tipo de form apenas com alguns desses dados, tanto faz setar os dados primeiro e depois salvar a entidade, ou usar apenas o save().

Comment: Obrigado StatelessDev. Só mais uma dúvida: No método de editar que irei criar separado está correto do jeito que fiz? Carrego do banco, dou o set e depois uso o save: 

`Optional<Pessoa> pessoa = pessoaRepository.findById(pessoaedicao.getId()); 
pessoa.get().setNome(pessoaedicao.getNome()); 
pessoa.get().setSobrenome(pessoaedicao.getSobrenome()); 
pessoaRepository.save(pessoa.get());  `

Como eu disse, apenas usando o save() funciona. Existe o mais correto? Carregar, setar e salvar, ou apenas salvar como abaixo? 
`pessoaRepository.save(pessoaedicao); `

Comment: Se o seu objeto já chega com as alterações, basta salvar. Não faz sentido gastar recurso do sistema para ir ao banco de dados e recuperar dados que você já tenha em mãos. Sua ideia é otimizar sempre que possível. Para falar a verdade, seu sistema é tão simples que você poderia usar o mesmo endpoint para criar uma pessoa nova ou editar. A questão é que no mundo real, em geral, você vai precisar de dois endpoints, visto que normalmente você vai aplicar regras de negócio antes de, efetivamente, salvar no banco.

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Jpa Repository já atualiza dinamicamente caso o id da entidade que você esteja enviando exista, uma forma trivial e bem utilizada no mercado é a validação se o registro já existe no banco de dados para evitar utilizar o Put como "post" permitindo sua criação, ficaria algo parecido com isso

```
            User userupdate = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("o id não foi encontrado na base"));
```

No caso da senha é uma particularidade que eu penso que é uma atenção adicional de validação para "evitar" ficar trafegando sua senha por mais que criptografada seria algo a se pensar.

A exception colocada no código é uma personalização para indicar a camada superior que o recurso não foi encontrado evitando essa dupla função do endpoint de update executar tanto atualização quanto criação